# How to find related pages without querying inside a loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, html

I'm having an issue with a site I'm programming. Things are a bit slow on a site section where I have pages and child pages. 
I've got a lot of mySQL queries specifically at this section, there are more than 20 queries being executed at the same time, 
making me wait up to 5 seconds until anything show up.

I read this question [Is 20 SQL Queries per page load really considered a lot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342504/is-20-sql-queries-per-page-load-really-considered-a-lot) and figured out that I indeed have a problem... and madlep's answer mentioned this N+1 situation where I query the database inside a foreach for every page, looking for its children.

Here goes an example (I'm using Laravel, by the way):

```
 $pages = Page::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get(array('id', 'title', 'slug'));
 foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $children = Page::where('parent_id', '=', $page->id)->get(array('id', 'title', 'slug'));
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $grandChildren = Page::where('parent_id', '=', $child->id)->get(array('id', 'title', 'slug'));
    }
 }
```

Being a newbie, I'm tring to find out a better way to handle this, reducing the page queries.

The question is: how can I fetch the child pages outside a foreach loop? Everything is done dynamically, so I need a flexible approach to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are tracking a relatively small # of items (e.g. Web Pages), I would be pulling these from a Cached datastructure that holds the entire Heirarchy and can be queried in RAM rather than issuing a database query.  You could build this cached structure when the app starts, and have it rebuild periodically via a task/job if you are making changes to the pages on a frequent bases.  However, if this is not an option, you really need to re-write an entire SQL query that performs the return of the full recordset as a single SET OPERATION, rather than performing multiple queries using the code logic.  Your ORM may have a way to deal with N+1's, but generally they tell you to re-write queries or restructure your tables to avoid the N+1.

Cache Structure Example
A Dictionary in the form of : CurrentPageId, ParentPageId

Any page where the ParentPageId is null is a root level page.

Comment: That helped me a lot. TY very much. 
I'm using Laravel cache now, thing got much quicker.
There is only one downfall: when the user updates or insert content, he will have to wait until the cache expires. I wonder how big sites like StackOverflow handle this issue. How to maintain cache and make it rebuild it when the DB changes?

Comment: Generally, your ORM Cache handles all traffic against the database, so updates and inserts that flow "through" the ORM, are already tracked.  If you are modifying the database directly (not through the ORM), you are really fighting the framework.  If you have only noticed this in testing, and don't plan on doing ad-hoc inserts/updates via the database once it is in production, then there is no reason to really worry about it.