# How to speed up a page with >100 mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I have a PHP page on my website, that uses over 100 mysql queries. All the queries are different, and are all just `SELECT` queries from multiple tables. On average, the page takes about 5 seconds to load, and I wish to improve this time.

What method of optimization do I have? I did some research, and took a look into memcache (I don't know how it works, what it can do or if it applies to my situation, so help may be appreciated), but as I said, I don't know if that is applicable to my situation.

I was also thinking of a query caching program, but don't know of any I can use?

Any help?

Comment: May be use ajax to load the content side by side so that when visitor comes to the page u start loading some static content and simultaneously load the other contents which uses the expensive queries. So if user comes on the page they immediately see the static content and before moving eye around you have already loaded the other contents using AJAX.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342504/is-20-sql-queries-per-page-load-really-considered-a-lot

Comment: http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/what-are-lot-mysql-queries-per-page-t83201.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of options for MySQL.

First is to setup a [Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) in your MySQL config. If your program is `SELECT` heavy, try setting `low-priority-updates` to on. This gives higher priority on the server to SELECT statements, and less priority to INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements.

Changing MySQL's use of memory might be a good idea, especially if you use a lot of `JOIN` statements - I usually set the `join_buffer_size` to about 8M.

From a PHP point-of-view, try [caching results](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php).

Edit: the class down the [forum page](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/what-are-lot-mysql-queries-per-page-t83201.html) that [Suresh Kamrushi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900692/suresh-kamrushi) posted is a nice way of caching in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some points which might be useful to optimize your page load:

MySQL:

1. Enable Query Cache
2. Select with only specific columns, avoid select * from syntax
3. Avoid Co-related inner queries
4. Use Indexing
5. Avoid too many queries. If possible then try to use joins/unions

---

PHP:

1. Use singleton methodology to avoid multiple database instances
2. If possible, try calculation work in SQL as well.

HTML:

1. CDN to load images/js/css parallely
2. Sprite images
3. JS include in footer